# Problems compiling Android project to Mobile device "Pixel"

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I am using Delphi 10.2 Tokyo.  I want to develop on my new Android Pixel.  After installing the necessary programs, etc, I try to compile a simple "Hello World" program, but always gets this error message:

> [DCC Error] E2597 C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\CatalogRepository\AndroidNDK-9c_x86\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: fatal error: .\Android\Debug\libAndroid_Test_Proj.so: open: Permission denied

Are there any solutions?

Comment: Have you tried your "Hello World" program on a different Android phone?

Comment: Where do you have your project files located?

Comment: Have you enabled Developer mode on the device?

Comment: I have not tried "Hello World" program on a different phone.
I have enabled Developer mode on my device.

Comment: My project is located in this folder on my laptop:
C:\Users\larsh\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\Projects\_Android_Test

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved my moving my project folder from the above mentioned location to a folder directly in the root (c:\mobiledevelopment). 
I have tried something like this before. I had a sqlite database located in the debug folder of my default project folder. I got an error telling me that the database was locked. When I moved the databse to a folder in the rootdirectory (c:\sqlite) the problem was solved.
An explanation of this would be most wellcome!
Best regards
Lars